# ListView after populate doesnt refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I am working with ListView which is populated with external excel file, reading works, but am trying solve some issue almost 4 days on this moment - ListView is not showing changed state of  these objects.

After setting ItemsSource Property of ListView object with array of custom ListViewItem objects using data-binding after changing values in objects ListView is not showing new state of these objects

Here is xaml code

```
 <ListView Name="databaseListView" Height="333" Background="Silver">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding 
    Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"></CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="City" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Personal Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonalPhone}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Call Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CallStatus}" Width="100"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

And here is custom c# class:

```
class MyListViewItem
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PersonalPhone { get; set; }
        public string CallStatus { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

For example such code doesnt affect ListView (assuming there are few items in ListView selected)

```
foreach(MyListViewItem item in databaseListView.SelectedItems){
   item.IsSelected = true;//or false also doesnt work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your getters/setters to fire the `PropertyChanged` event of the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification) interface.

I.E., change `public bool IsSelected { get; set; }` to:

```
class MyListViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
    }
}
```

then add the following function to your `MyListViewItem` class

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```